# Can anyone help how to auto-reconnect my keyboard from changing connection between devices

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm using Keychron K1 bluetooth keyboard.

I'm using this keyboard between 1 pc and 2 laptops. My Windows pc and laptop automatically reconnect to the keyboard when I press fn + 1 or fn + 2 to change connection, but my last laptop, which ubuntu is installed, doesn't reconnect when I press fn + 3, which I used to connect laptop with ubuntu.

tried bluetoothctl and trust device address, but didn't work.
tried startup application preference also didn't work.

any other solutions?

p.s. Mind my English, which isn't my first language.

Comment: According to this https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k1-wireless-mechanical-keyboard it can indeed support up to 3 devices but also the supported OSes are Windows/Android/Mac/iOS, not desktop Linux. Regardless, it probably works with Ubuntu by following the *adapted* instructions for Windows. Pressing FN+3 for 3 seconds enables pairing mode and right after that you should open Settings > Bluetooth were the keyboard should be visible and click to pair.

Comment: PS - Your English can be improved like everybody else's but it's fine as it is. I've seen much worse form native speakers.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's issue: they have already paired the keyboard in ubuntu, and when switching back to ubuntu the OS doesn't reconnect to the keyboard. They don't want to have to re-pair every time they switch devices. I can confirm that that I reproduce this with another brand of bluetooth keyboard - but my bluetooth mouse can switch between devices without issues on ubuntu.